# JavaFX обращение к элементам ComboBox

Tags: javafx, combobox

Есть ли методы, позволяющие извлекать значение элемента заполненного combo-boxa по индексу, и считать общее количество элементов (аналогично MASSIVE[i] и MASSIVE.length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Количество элементов:

```
comboBox.getItems().size();
```

Определенный элемент:

```
comboBox.getItems().get(i);
```

См. [ObservableList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html) и сопутствующие классы коллекций.